# Transition with 3d rotation spins differently in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I make an arrow, using two borders of a box and rotating the box. When clicking it, the arrow should point up instead of down, and use a transition.

In Chrome/Safari/Firefox this works corretly. In IE11 however, it rotates weirdly. It ends up in the correct orientation, but gets there differently/around other axis than in the other browsers.

```
button:after {
  /* make a box with two borders */
  content: "";
  border-left: 1.5px solid blue;
  border-top: 1.5px solid blue;
  transition: all 1s;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  /* rotate to give illusion of arrows */
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform-origin: 25% 25%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 25% 25%;
}
/* change direction of arrow */
button.open:after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(-135deg);
}
```

Interactive example, click the button:
https://jsfiddle.net/b51sctnu/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's a good idea to keep the changes **easy** for the browser to understand

In your case, use 2 transforms that are the most similar posible.

Since the final step is

```
  transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(-135deg);
```

in the initial step use:

```
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(-135deg);
```

The 0deg rotation seems useless, but matches the final transform

Example, changing the new state to a hover to make easier to go back and forth

```css
button:after {
  content: "";
  border-left: 1.5px solid blue;
  border-top: 1.5px solid blue;
  transition: all 1s;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 25% 25%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform-origin: 25% 25%;
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(-135deg);
} 
button:hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(-135deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(-135deg);
}
button {
  border: 0px;
  background: grey;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button>asdasd</button>
```

Comment: Felt I had tried every combination, but apparently not. This works, thank you.

Comment: Happy that it helped !